# Error "Must declare the scalar variable" when using a reserved word in a SqlParameter

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, reserved-words

We're migrating a database backend from Access to SQL Server.

One of the field names is `Key`. Now `Key` is [a reserved word in both Access and SQL Server](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/what-are-reserved-access-odbc-and-sql-server-keywords.html) so the workaround in Access was always to put square brackets around the field name.

When connecting to Access we generated an `OleDBParameter` collection for each `OleDBCommand`. Checking the command's `CommandText` at run time it would read something like `UPDATE Foo SET [Key]=? WHERE etc` because remember OleDB/Access doesn't have named parameters, only `?`. That was all fine.

Fast forward to present day and using SQL Server we do a similar thing with `SqlCommand` and `SQLParameter`. So, at runtime the `CommandText` reads something like `UPDATE Foo SET [Key]=@Key WHERE etc` because SQL doesn't like the old question mark thing and we have to start using named parameters.

Trouble is the application chokes on this command, saying:

`Incorrect syntax near 'varchar'. Must declare the scalar variable "@Key"`

It's only the table with the field name `Key` which is affected. Everything else has survived the migration to SQL and the other tables (with no reserved words for field names) are fine.

I understand that one of the solutions is to avoid using a reserved word as a field name but I am hoping for an answer that allows us to work around the reserved word as we always used to.

Comment: Could you post the block of code that you use for the command and its parameter binding? It would be great to see your code so that we'll be able to tell if the `@Key` is an undeclared variable/parameter or that nothing is being bound to that value placeholder..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the error has anything to do with Key being a keyword.  It wants you tell it what the value of @Key is.

So you have your command, and then you define the parameter:

```
Dim cmd As New Sqlcommand("Update Foo SET [Key]=@Key", connection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Key", SomeValue)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I usually encounter that error because I forgot to actually define the parameter.

Comment: you're right that works ... mmm but i don't know why my more long winded version (not using `AddWithValue`) doesn't ... see my edit. i'm going to carry on trying to figure it out

Comment: you don't have the @ in your name for the parameter, also you didn't add it to the commands parameters.

Comment: again, you're right: in simplifying in order copy to stackoverflow, i've skipped adding it to the command's parameters. this isn't the problem in the original though. still looking at it.

Comment: Is the @ in the part where you add it in your regular code? replacing this: p = New SqlParameter("Key", SqlDbType.VarChar) with p = New SqlParameter("@Key", SqlDbType.VarChar)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. We had some code which generated the `CommandText` automatically from the list of parameters. If the parameter is a reserved word then the `CommandText` needs to have the square brackets around the field name but the parameter itself can't have any brackets.

Of course, in the good|bad old days of Access and OleDB it was just:

```
... SET [Key]=?
```

which was fine.

Our updated SQLClient code was generating either:

```
... SET [Key]=@[Key]
```

or else (if we removed the brackets):

```
... SET Key=@Key
```

neither of which is going to work, since what we need (thanks @D..) is:

```
... SET [Key]=@Key
```

Looks like our CommandText automagical generator code will need a bit of re-engineering. Either that or we purge all reserved words.